# Solr Could not load driver: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

Tags: jdbc, solr, odbc

When I try to dataimport I receive this error:

> Could not load driver: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

This is the log:

```
Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Could not load driver: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:262)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:411)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:483)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.handleRequestBody(DataImportHandler.java:185)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1962)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Could not load driver: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:402)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:315)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:223)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Could not load driver: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.createConnectionFactory(JdbcDataSource.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.init(JdbcDataSource.java:66)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.getDataSourceInstance(DataImporter.java:383)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.ContextImpl.getDataSource(ContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.init(SqlEntityProcessor.java:53)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.init(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:74)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:419)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:400)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver or org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:905)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.createConnectionFactory(JdbcDataSource.java:116)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:490)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:421)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:895)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:474)
    ... 36 more
```

Where could I find this drivder to place it in `C:\solr-4.9.0\example\solr\lib` Since my solr instance in sub-folder of `solr` of the previous path.

Comment: Which Java version? The jdbc-odbc driver is no longer included with Java 8.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes it is Java 8. I tried to search for jdbc driver for mbd but I could not find it. So where could I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes it is Java 8.

The JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java 8.

> I tried to search for jdbc driver for mdb but I could not find it. So where could I get it?

You could use [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html). For more information see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)

Comment: In addition: the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc/ shows how to install UCanAccess with Solr, by copying the five files into the lib directory at the Solr Home directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the updated jdbc driver into the pc thats hosting solr.